# Apollo client GraphQL query returns undefined error and data while being stuck on loading

Tags: react-native, api, graphql

I am very new to graphql and react native. I set up a graphql API and tested it with the playground app. All my queries return a JSON. I then tried to set up my apollo client inside of expo react native app. Now every time I run a query an undefined value is returned. this is how it is set up in my App.js.

```js
const cache = new InMemoryCache()
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'http://192.168.0.1:8000/graphql',
    cache,
    defaultOptions: {
        watchQuery: { fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network' }
    },
})

export default function App() {

    const [loadingCache, setLoadingCache] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        persistCache({
            cache,
            storage: AsyncStorage,
        }).then(() => setLoadingCache(false))
    }, [])

    if (loadingCache) {
        return <Text>Loading ....</Text>
    }

    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            ... react native nav stuff ...
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
```

My data screen and query looks like this

```js
const GET_JOBS_QUERY = gql`
query jobs {
    jobs {
        id
        name
        description
    }
}`

export default function Jobs() {
    const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(GET_JOBS_QUERY);
    if (loading) return <Text>Loading ...</Text>;
    if (data) {  console.log({data}); }
}
```

I'm using expo to test the app and I only get undefined as a return value for both error and data. I also tried calling API from a mobile API testing app that queries grphql and I was able to get back proper data. But when using the app through expo it fails consistently.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Any update on this ? am getting same error ?